# How to copy the input text on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy

I am looking to copy the text written in an input when the user click on a button. How can I do it ?

Here is my HTML structure :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>2b2tyoung.tk</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div label>
            Join server 
        </div>
        <div class="copy-text">
            <input type="text" class="text" value="2b2tyoung.tk">
            <button>
                <i class="fa fa-clone"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: People expect to see what you tryed, so don't hesitate to add your code supposed to copy your text by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here I selected the `fa-clone` icon, added a listener on click, then I copied the value of the input.

```js
document.querySelector(".fa-clone").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let input = document.querySelector(".copy-text input");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value);
  console.log("copied "+input.value)
})
```

```html
<div class="copy-text">
  <input type="text" class="text" value="2b2tyoung.tk">
  <button>
    <i class="fa fa-clone">Clone</i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>2b2tyoung.tk</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div label>Join server</div>
      <div class="copy-text">
        <input type="text" class="text" value="2b2tyoung.tk" />
        <button onclick="copyInputValue()">
          <i class="fa fa-clone"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  function copyInputValue() {
    const ipt = document.querySelector("#app input");
    ipt.select();
    const copyed = document.execCommand("copy");
    if (copyed) {
      alert("copy success!");
    } else {
      alert("copy failed!");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If someone asks a relatively simple question like this one they are probably missing some basic context like for example how the query selector works or how you actually copy the value from the input field so it would probably be helpful for them if you would explain a little bit in comments